# JavaScript decoding function skipping "Z" while decoding

Tags: javascript

i am decoding a endoded string in javascript function it works fine but if a "Z" comes in string it skips it 
here is the function

```
function getData() {
    var value="DsaEncemohaY46726374722147(~ju~zzgboj667zzzDsaEncemohaY46726374722>71(~ju~zzgboj667zzzEPUrgum./Y46726370447>51(~ju~zzgboj667zzzEPUrgumY4672636>7>7166(~ju~zzgboj667zzz^+G742Y.VE266+76Y+JOHM/Y46726373727?34Y46726370475?53(~ju~zzgboj667";
    var to_dec = value;
    var xor_key = 6;
    var result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < to_dec.length; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(xor_key ^ to_dec.charCodeAt(i));
    }
    return result;

}
```

expected output is

```
"BugChecking_20140512144721.xlsx||adil001|||BugChecking_20140512144817.xlsx||adil001|||CVStask(Z)_20140516221837.xlsx||adil001|||CVStask_20140508181700.xlsx||adil001|||X-A124_(PC400-10_Z-LINK)_20140515141952_20140516213935.xlsx||adil001"
```

but it gives

```
"BugChecking_20140512144721.xlsx||adil001|||BugChecking_20140512144817.xlsx||adil001|||CVStask()_20140516221837.xlsx||adil001|||CVStask_20140508181700.xlsx||adil001|||X-A124_(PC400-10_-LINK)_20140515141952_20140516213935.xlsx||adil001"
```

you can see it neglects "Z" from  `(PC400-10_Z-LINK)` and `CVStask(Z)`

Comment: Seem to decode fine here http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/gqgkk/

Comment: it might be producing a character which is not visible. and character would not be 'Z'

Comment: What do you mean "if a 'Z' comes"?  Can you give us an example?